# Ubuntu 18.04 freezing randomly with home-built computer

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, logs

I have a home-built desktop:

- AMD Ryzen 7 1700x
- 16Gb (2x8) Corsair Vengeance RAM
- NVidia GeForce GT 1030

---

- Kernel: 4.15.0-38-generic
- Nvidia Proprietary Driver 410.73

I have been having this problem since I installed Ubuntu 18.04, however, I used to think it only occurred when my display went to sleep (I turned suspend off). This is the first time it has happened while I was using the computer.

Essentially the desktop freezes and the keyboard and mouse go completely unresponsive so I have to restart the computer using the power switch. After rebooting everything works normally again until it freezes again. I have not noticed a pattern of when it freezes. The RAM or CPU are never overloaded and the temps are fine.

I looked in my logs and it seems that there may be some issues?

[image: 'Important' Logs]

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: May be bad RAM. Run memtest available on the boot menu of the Ubuntu installation media to check.

Comment: I ran a memory test when I initially built the machine but I will give this a go. When you say in the boot menu do you mean boot into recovery mode and look for the option there? Thanks!

Comment: No. Boot on the installation media you used to install Ubuntu originally.

Comment: I used memtest86 since it works with uefi. Ran 4 passes with no errors. Any idea what those errors are in the logs file?

Comment: Next step is disabling all vendor specific drivers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'vendor specific'. Isn't a driver by definition specific to the device? I rolled back my graphics driver to 390 instead of 410 and am going to wait and see what that does. I also tried the open source Nouveau driver but then I couldn't open any programs (it kept kicking me back to the login screen when I tried to click on program)

Comment: nvidea has their own closed source driver, in addition to the open source one supported by canonical.

Comment: Update: same issue even with a different graphics driver

Comment: Check the smart status of the disk.

Comment: Note that even if the GUI freezes (which in turn makes the local keyboard and mouse unusable) the rest of the system may still be functional so if you have a running ssh connection from another machine that may still work and you can use that to investigate log files on the live system.

Comment: A few places i found online stated that some AMD processors suffer from a segfault issue that can cause freezing on linux. I ran the kill-ryzen script found on github and indeed got a segfault error. I contacted AMD, and they are sending me a new processor. I will update when I get the new processor whether that fixes the issue or not.

Comment: I received my new processor and reinstalled it. After several days of monitoring... I have the same issue. The only difference is now that when my display won't wake my mouse and keyboard are responsive (their lights are on).

Answer (score 0):

If your RAM tests okay, try changing the NVDIA driver. If your motherboard has onboard video, try removing the video card.

Comment: There is no onboard video, just the graphics card. I was using the 396 driver initially and had the same problem. I ran a memory test initially when I installed everything but I will try again.

Comment: Do you have another video card you can swap in temporarily for testing?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. At this point I kind of wish I hadn’t bought the Nvidia card since there seems to be so many issues with the drivers, but when I initially asked around everyone seemed to say any graphics card should work fine with Ubuntu. Is it really the graphics card that would cause the whole system to go unresponsive?

Comment: Modern Ubuntu’s use the GPU quite a bit for the desktop.

Comment: I tried different drivers. Same issues.

Comment: You can see on the NVIDIA forums that screen freezes are a big problem in the Windows version as well.